# Bouncy Castle not found in classpath, but works when run in maven

Tags: java, classpath, maven-3, bouncycastle

This is a very weird error, that I don't know more about how to fix it.

I'm using [Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/) libs to decrypt a password. I configured it in my maven pom.xml as:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
  <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15</artifactId>
  <version>1.46</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

The *provided* scope is because it is a signed jar. It is a command-line application and I use maven-assembly-plugin to generate a jar with all the dependencies included. I can't include it because, as a signed jar, it would break the signature verification. Marking it as *provided* it isn't included in the generated jar.

So I try to pass it in the classpath with the command:

```
java -cp bcprov-jdk15-1.46.jar -jar my_executable.jar
```

but when I run, I get a Class not found exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/BouncyCastleProvider
```

I've tried dozens of ways to run it, but always get the same error.

But what is really weird is that my unit tests that use the library run fine. If I type `mvn test`, the exact code that fails when I run from the command-line works fine. If I go to my `~/.m2` repo and rename the `bcprov-jdk15-1.46.jar`, the tests fail with the same Class Not Found Error.

Why my code can run from inside maven, but fails from a jar with dependencies file? I'm really lost.

Comment: Can you have maven print the classpath?

Comment: Can you place the bcprov-jdk15-1.46.jar into JAVA_HOME\lib\ext\, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it putting the Bouncy Castle jar inside the Java installation in `$JAVA_HOME\lib\ext\`